# crash on rangeexception index beyound bound

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i have some process running in the background using OperationQueue , it getting crashed and error is **"'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
"**in the App delegate , i am not getting where is the error

> on this line it get crashed

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

Comment: somewhere you are trying to access value out of range of array

Comment: Set the Exception Breakpoint to get the *real* place where the crash occurs.

Comment: sometimes it does not give error and works is it because of the opearationQueue?

Comment: Can you show the line of code where you are trying to get objects from array?

Comment: func objectAtIndex(index : Int) -> Any? {
   
      return booklist?[index] }

Comment: on the above line the exception breakpoint threw the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get an object from an index of your **booklist** `array` which does not even exist. The exception says, **You trying to get an object from index 2 but you have only 2 objects in your array.** Try to check before getting an object from array like below:

```
func objectAtIndex(index : Int) -> Any? { 
    if index < booklist.count {
        return booklist?[index] 
    } else {
        //The index does not exist in the array.
    }
}
```